# Plotly hover info with multiple rows at the same coordinates only shows first row information

Tags: python, plotly

I've been experimenting with plotly and bokeh, basically trying to reproduce the same dashboard with each to see which I prefer. With Bokeh hovertool it shows all observations at a single lat/long coordinate. With plotly so far I can only get it to show the first observation. I've looked at the documentation but I didn't see an answer. My current code is below as is a sample of the data.

```
+----------+----------+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| Leg_Orig | Leg_Dest | MAILG_CTY_NM | Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm | total_seats | dest_lat   | dest_long | duration_hours |             |              |             |
+----------+----------+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| ATL      | BOS      | BOSTON       | MASSACHUSETTS | USA         | 2020-01-10 | 22:30:00  | 118            | 42.36429977 | -71.00520325 | 2.416666667 |
| ATL      | BOS      | BOSTON       | MASSACHUSETTS | USA         | 2020-01-10 | 18:00:00  | 47             | 42.36429977 | -71.00520325 | 2.583333333 |
| ATL      | BOS      | BOSTON       | MASSACHUSETTS | USA         | 2020-01-10 | 21:10:00  | 59             | 42.36429977 | -71.00520325 | 2.483333333 |
| ATL      | BOS      | BOSTON       | MASSACHUSETTS | USA         | 2020-01-10 | 19:57:00  | 21             | 42.36429977 | -71.00520325 | 2.55        |
+----------+----------+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import geopandas
import geoplot
import json
cities = pd.read_csv('/Users/620751/Documents/cities.csv')
import plotly.express as px
import plotly
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(cities, lat="dest_lat", lon="dest_long", 
                        hover_name="MAILG_CTY_NM", 
                        hover_data=["Leg_Dep_Dt_Tm", "seats","duration_hours"],
                        color_discrete_sequence=["fuchsia"], zoom=1, height=300)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
#py.iplot(fig)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve](/help/mcve)? You should provide (at least) a sample of your original `df`.

Comment: @jwstraveler Could you include a screenshot of the hoverifo?